# File Uploading using Server.MapPath() and FileUpload.SaveAs()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website admin section which I'm busy working on, which has 4 FileUpload controls for specific purposes. I need to know that , when I use the `Server.MapPath()` Method Within the FileUpload control's `SaveAs()` methods, Will it still be usable on the web server after I have uploaded the website? As far as I know, `SaveAs()` requires an absolute path, that's why I map a path with `Server.MapPath()`

```
if (fuLogo.HasFile) //My FileUpload Control : Checking if a file has been allocated to the control
        {
            int counter = 0;  //This counter Is used to ensure that no files are overwritten.
            string[] fileBreak = fuLogo.FileName.Split(new char[] { '.' });
            logo = Server.MapPath("../Images/Logos/" + fileBreak[0] + counter.ToString()+ "." + fileBreak[1]);  // This is the part Im wondering about. Will this still function the way it should on the webserver after upload?
            if (fileBreak[1].ToUpper() == "GIF" || fileBreak[1].ToUpper() == "PNG")
            {
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(logo))
                {
                    counter++; //Here the counter is put into action
                    logo = Server.MapPath("../Images/Logos/" + fileBreak[0] + counter.ToString() + "." + fileBreak[1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cvValidation.ErrorMessage = "This site does not support any other image format than .Png or .Gif . Please save your image in one of these file formats then try again.";
                cvValidation.IsValid = false;
            }
            if (fuLogo.PostedFile.ContentLength > 409600 )  //File must be 400kb or smaller
            {
                cvValidation.ErrorMessage = "Please use a picture with a size less than 400 kb";
                cvValidation.IsValid = false;

            }
            else
            {

                if (fuLogo.HasFile && cvValidation.IsValid)
                {
                    fuLogo.SaveAs(logo); //Save the logo if file exists and Validation didn't fail. The path for the logo was created by the Server.MapPath() method.
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            logo = "N/A";
        }
```

Comment: Oh, and Logo is a string variable declared in global scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you intend to save the files in
  a directory on your web server , then
  the `Server.MapPath()` will be the suitable
  solution.

  `string dirPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/Images/Logos/"+ fileBreak[0] + counter.ToString() + "." + fileBreak[1];`

  Look [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- if you intend to save your files out
  the web server then

  Use a full path, like "c:\uploads"
  and be sure that the web process has
  permission to write to that folder,I suggest you store the path itself in the web.config file in this case.

Comment: very handy Information you handed there, in your second point. I'm gonna research how to do that quick before I pop another vein at the customer support

Comment: The Full paths are stored in the database, and i intend to upload the images in the Images/Logos Directory. The path would be read out of the database, and broken down into the rooted path which is required to access this newly uploaded image.

Comment: In IIS, I right clicked on the application's folder that contains the web.config.  Properties --> Security --> Edit.  Click on the IIS_IUSRS, and gave it permission to modify.  Then I was able to upload my file.

Answer (score 3):

yes, that can be used after saving file and when you try retrieve that file...

```
Server.MapPath("~/Images/Logos/" + uploadedFileName);
```

Comment: reason why the server.MapPath had a ../Images/Logos is that it had to go back one directory , then head into Images/Logos.  I'm glad it would work on the webserver, because I read somewhere that Server.MapPath() doesn't always work as expected once your page is uploaded.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: try to always use ~ sign, that will start from root Directory.

Comment: so Should I change it to ~/../Images/Logos ? :?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should still work as [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) uses the relative values and returns the complete physical path.

Comment: The result I had for an image named Test.Png was 

C:/TestSite/Images/Logos/Test0.Png  (as a newly saved file), and that was the result i was looking for. Just wanted to know if I would still be able to access the file on the webserver (when uploaded to the webserver). It would obviously end up in a relative Images/Logos/ Directory. Just, would it be uploaded legitimately and usable by my website when i try and access that test0.png?

Answer (score 0):

It's one line of code:

```
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" ")+"\\YourImageDirectoryOnServer\\"+FileUpload1.FileName);
```