# C# Upload Files on another partition of the server

Tags: c#

I'm using FileUpload.SaveAs() function of C# to upload files to the server but I want to save the files on another partition. Let us say, save the files on Drive D of the server instead on the current drive which is Drive C. Please share your thoughts. Thanks is advance.

I have learned that using full path such as

```
 FileUpload.SaveAs("D:\FileUpload");
```

will save the file outside the web server.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816699/file-uploading-using-server-mappath-and-fileupload-saveas) out.

To simplify the question, how can I upload files on the other partition of the server that hosts my web app?

Comment: Are you having a specific issue? If so please show your code and tell us details of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Then specific a different path....

Comment: If I just specify a different path. It will save outside the server. It uploads on the client computer.

Comment: @rbenitez: That statement doesn't make sense.  Can you demonstrate with some sample code and values in the question?  "save outside the server" and "uploads on the client computer" aren't clear.

Comment: The files were uploaded on the Drive D of my computer instead of the server's Drive D.

Comment: @rbenitez: Where is the code running?  If this is an ASP.NET application running on the server then it absolutely does *not* save to the client's computer.  If the application is *running* on your workstation then your workstation *is* the server and it will save wherever you tell it to save.  It's really not clear what the problem is here.  There are two hosts in question.  Which one is running the web application, which one is running the web browser, and what are the paths being used?

Comment: @rbenitez: Regarding your edit... What do you mean by "outside the web server"?  Whatever computer is running the code will save the file to the path specified as seen by that computer.  It's not magic.  When you save a file to `D:\FileUpload` then it will save to `D:\FileUpload` as known by that computer.  If the `D` drive perhaps maps to another machine on the network, then it'll save to another machine.  But the file system is clear.  It will save the file where you tell it to save.

Comment: It is running on ASP.Net. The client computers running the web application should be able to save the files on the Drive D of the web server. Files were save on Drive C using Server.MapPath()

Comment: @rbenitez: If the client computer is "running the web application" then the client computer *is* the server.  Whichever machine is hosting the application (in IIS or whatever web server is being used) is the server.  If you want to save the file to another machine then that server needs to have file system access to that other machine.  The "D" drive isn't a universal concept, each machine has its own.  In order to save to the other computer's "D" drive then the computer running the code needs to have a drive mapped to that network location.

Comment: It is hosted on a server with IIS. Oh please, I know the concepts about those drive I just want to explain the scenario that's why I've said "D". Now to simplify the question, how can I upload files on the other partition of host server?

Comment: @rbenitez: By using the exact line of code you've shown in the question.  There's clearly something else going on here which you're not telling us.  But the fact remains that if the code is instructed to save to "D:\FileUpload" then it will save to "D:\FileUpload".  What you haven't been able to do is specify what the runtime values are, how the computers are communicating, etc.  We can't help you without more information.  I guarantee this isn't a bug in the `FileUpload` object, it's something in your setup.

Comment: I don't know why your are not getting my point. It is simple as this: I have a web application hosted on the server. Users will upload files but when they upload files it is saving on their drive and not on the server's drive.

Comment: @rbenitez: And I don't know what you're not getting my point.  Based solely on that description, that *can't* happen.  HTTP doesn't work that way.  Something else is going on here which you're not telling us.  Does the server have file system access to the client?  What does that drive mapping look like?  When you debug this, what are the actual runtime values of the actual code you're using?  I *guarantee* you that if you expose this application to the internet and I use it, it *will not* save the file to my computer.

Comment: And I did not also say that it is a bug. I am just asking how would I save the files to web server or host's another partition.

Comment: I disagree. I can save files to the server using HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(). I will assume that you know this function. And my problem using this function, I can only save file to the current directory which is the the Drive C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by using Virtual Directory of IIS and providing admin credentials for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx, the `String filename` is the full path name of the location to save. Meaning you should be able to do so e.g:

```
FileUpload.SaveAs("D:\where_you_want_to_save")
```

By the way what have you tried and what error did you get?

Comment: No errors but it will just save on the client computer not on the server.

Comment: You need to give us more information as that should not happen. Where is the method on?

Comment: Your code will only save the files on the directory of the current computer running the application. It should be saved on a different partition of the server that hosts the web application.

Comment: @rbernitez you need path of server.

Comment: That can only happen if the application is running on the same server i.e IIS running app and browser accessing app on same machine. Also check out you statement `will save the file outside the web server.` Browsers don't access client drives and similar resources unless things like Java applets are used.

Comment: "will save the file outside the web server" means that the files are not uploaded on the web server but being saved to the drives of the client users/computer that is accessing the hosted web app.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx), it would appear that `.SaveAs()` accepts a fully qualified file name as a parameter.  You could potentially use a `Path` object to cleanly build a path for the file, or just specify one directly as a string:

```
uploader.SaveAs("d:\\someFolder\\someFile.ext");
```

Comment: If I just specify a different path. It will save outside the server. It uploads on the client computer.

Comment: Your code will only save the files on the directory of the current computer running the application. It should be saved on a different partition of the server that hosts the web application.

Comment: @rbenitez: Again, as in comments above, "the current computer running the application" *is* "the server that hosts the application."  Whatever computer is *running the code* is the server.  The server does not, *can not by design*, save a file to the client.  Web servers can't write to a web client's local filesystem.  HTTP doesn't work that way.

Comment: IKR. I mean, the client users  when they upload a file it is saved on their drives not on the server's drive.